# bottom align containers items with bootstrap or css

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Is there a way to bottom align all containers items of the parent div with either bootstrap or css. It looks like every single child item seats in the middle of the parent:

http://www.bootply.com/Bvp8d2s04w

Here is an image, please notice items with red and green backgrounds, I would like them to bottom align with parent container:

[image]

Comment: Please include the relevant bits of your code in your question, preferably in a code snippet if possible.

Comment: the other parts of the code are not needed

Comment: Not the point, per the guidelines of the site you're supposed to include the relevant pieces of your code in your question. What if Bootply goes belly up, is down, or deletes your ply? Your question is likely pretty useless to someone viewing it in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make the container as a `flexbox` (`display: flex`) then align all children to the bottom with `align-items: flex-end`:

```css
.form-inline { display: flex; align-items: flex-end; }
.form-inline * { margin-bottom: 0; vertical-align: bottom; display: inline-block; }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<form novalidate="" name="categoryForm" ng-submit="vm.saveCategory()">
  <div class="form-inline" style="background-color:lightgreen;">
    <label style="display:inline;">{{ vm.category.name }}</label>
    <input type="button" value="Edit" ng-click="showEditCategory()" style="margin-left:20px" class="btn btn-sm btn-default">
    <div style="display:inline" ng-show="vm.showEditCategory">
      <input type="text" ng-model="vm.category.name" id="name" name="name" class="form-control" value="{{vm.category.name}}" required="">
      <span ng-show="categoryForm.name.$error.required" class="text-warning">Name is required</span>
      <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-sm btn-success" ng-disabled="categoryForm.$invalid">
    </div>
    <div style="display:inline" class="label label-danger" ng-show="vm.categoryErrorMessage">
      {{ vm.categoryErrorMessage }}
    </div>
    <div style="display:inline" ng-show="vm.categorySuccessMessage">
      <span class="label label-success"> {{ vm.categorySuccessMessage }}</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/azizn/aem1sLwc/

P.S why would you need this?

Comment: This is not exactly what I am looking for. Take a look at the {{ vm.categoryErrorMessage }} element with a red background as an example. I would like that element to touch the bottom of the parent

Comment: Ok that wasn't clear at first. I've updated my answer using flexbox.

Comment: Perfect, this is exacty what I was after, thanks mate

Answer (score 0):

```css
.main{
border:1px solid;
  height: 300px;
  position:relative;
}
.red{
background:red;
  height: 100px;
  width:100px;
  display:inline-block;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0px;
}
  
.left{
  
  }
.right{
  right:0px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="main">
<div class="red left"></div>
<div class="red right"></div>
</div>
```

Here it is............

Comment: Yes, it is working fine here, but try to incorporate that within my example, with bootstrap in place, it looks like it is not so easy

Comment: form{
  bottom:0px;
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
}

Comment: please add this on to your example

Comment: i have tested that

Comment: last time this website showing problem in my browser, so that happens..

Comment: I have updated question, perhaps that will clear what I am after, it is so easy to accomplish it with pure css, but so difficult when intermingled with bootstrap

Comment: and the parent is div, not the form